# How do you make sure that you're adopting to a good home?

Tags: adoption

I came across a thread about avoiding giving pets to questionable people, not necessarily people who will mistreat the animals but turn them around and re-sell them.

If you have a pet that you need to put up for adoption for any reason, and don't want to put them in a shelter, how do you make sure that the pet is going to a good home?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick google search turned up this quiz: http://dogtime.com/quiz/am-i-ready-for-a-dog
I think the quiz is appropriate list of questions to ask your prospective adopters.

Some other things that come to mind:

**For pre-screening the people:**

- Do the adopters have prior experience with dogs (perhaps specifically
  with this breed)?
- Do they have realistic expectations of the dog :  ie. expect chewing,
  attention required, potty training can take up to 6 months of age,
  etc.
- Are they prepared for the financial obligation of a dog?  Some [sources](http://www.peteducation.com/article.cfm?c=2%202106&aid=1543) suggest owning a dog can cost anywhere from $800 - $2000 per year.  Food, flea/tick treatments, vet care + shots, treatments for things like UTIs, toys + treats, etc

**The environment is dependent on the dog:**

- A dog with a high prey drive (like a jack russel, for instance) will
  benefit much more from a fenced yard than dogs with little/no
  interest in chasing squirrels or cats.
- Dogs with high energy levels
  will not thrive in apartment environments.
- Other animals in the home can be
  considered

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the previous answer that includes the screening but a better way that you can avoid pet re-sellers is through the use of an [Adoption Contract or agreement](http://www.aforeverhome.org/forms/sample-adoption-contract/).  Pet re-sellers know to avoid signing these types of documents because of the potential penalties that they can incur.  A real pet adopter should not have a problem with an agreement like this.

The linked document can be modified for what ever other provisions you would like to include, though you should make sure that any provisions are enforceable in your area.

If the adopter is local, one good way is to do a walk through of the living environment that the pet will be living in.  You should be able to tell if the area is suited for the animal as well as maybe helping out the new owners to avoid some lessons that can be painful or expensive.  If the place is uncared for then chances are the pet will be similarly uncared for, if not immediately then probably with in a few months.  It is your discretion who you allow to adopt your animals, but you have to be strong enough to say no when your instincts tell you to.